# Ionic2/Cordova - No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I am facing the below error in my Ionic2 app when running in an Android device/emulator:

> No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

The error blocks all connexion to the backend and throws 403 error.

Any guesses on how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your html file(s):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="*"/>
```